# Assign an anonymous return value directly to a property of an object

Tags: javascript, json, anonymous-function

How can I assign the returned value of an anonymous function to a property of my JSON object?

Here's my scenario:

```
            selectOptionData.push({
                value: 123,
                text: 'Hi there',
                selected: false,
                transportObject: function(){
                    var transObj = null;
                    $.each(transports, function(i, t)
                    {
                        if (t.ID == currentTranspObjID) {
                            transObj = t;
                            return;
                        }
                    });

                    return transObj;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: [You don't have a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You have a normal JavaScript object defined with object literal notation.

I assume you want to execute the anonymous function immediately? Just add `()` after its body:

```
transportObject: (function(){
    var transObj = null;
    $.each(transports, function(i, t)
    {
        if (t.ID == currentTranspObjID) {
            transObj = t;
            return;
        }
     });
    return transObj;
}())  // <- see here
```

This is also called *immediate function* as you define and immediately execute it.

Comment: Felix thanks for the clarification. In fact i did that before posting my question but I added an ; in the end... like: (function(){....}()); and apparently thsi broke the plugin that i'm editing and I thought i did something wwrong... do you think in the plugin or it just can't have a ; in the end? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @byte_slave: No, if you put a `;` there, then you have invalid syntax. Between properties should only come `,` or nothing after the last property. Otherwise it would look like: `var obj = {foo:1,bar:0;};` which is wrong. The object definition is *one* statement, but `;` separates statements.

Comment: yeah...right right...i was thinking on  a function and not on a property anymore :( that's why... thanks for the enlightenment. Thanks a lot appreciated your help

Comment: that works. how would you that with arrow function ?

Comment: @Arfeen: `(() => {})()`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 123,
    text: "hi there",
    magics: (function () {
      // Do things.
      return "stuff";
    }())
};
```

Wrapping the function in parentheses lets you call the function in-line.